# How can I call JavaScript function on web page (not webview) that opened Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, html

We have customers who need to be able to talk to a device connected to the audio jack. Our customers can do web development but not android development.

Our goal was to create an app that stood between the web app and the SDK that talked to the audio connected device. I have code that launches our android app and our activity. I need to be able to send data back to the web page that opened our android app; preferably with a callback to a JavaScript function.

I can't use a webview because it is the customer's site (would be used with many customers and their respective sites). I thought about using local storage but I don't want the web page to get "stale" data saved from a previous call to the application.

Is it possible for an Android app to execute a callback function on a web page that loaded the Android app via an intent link? I have been feverishly searching and I can't seem to find anything.

I have called functions in a page loaded in web view but it will be an external page calling our application and need to send information back to that page.

I have examined the Intent object in the activity and can't anything I can hook into.

Comment: For anyone else wanting to do this, we are testing using a wss (secure web socket) server in the android app and a client in the web app. I will post back if we get some success.

Comment: Having good success communicating between web page and android app using web sockets. 

Using this web socket server library: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

And simple web socket api for web: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Note: You need to start your web socket server in a new thread in Android. Android will not allow this to run in the main UI thread.